# Windows 10 lockup with no error logs or bluescreen

Tags: windows, freeze, crash, logging, debug

Symptoms:

- Display image freezes on last frame
- No m/k inputs work whatsoever
- Audio freezes to a square wave sound at whatever pitch was last coming out of the speakers

There is seemingly no correlation to activity level. The system can be idling on a desktop, or running a high load game.

System:

- Win 10
- All new hardware about 2-4 months old
- NVMe SSD, Coffee Lake proc, GTX 1080, Gsync Monitor, 750W PSU

All drivers are up to date.

Things I've tried:

- Mem diagnostic tool, no issues found
- Searching through event viewer: there are absolutely no events that match with the lock-up time. Events start showing up chronologically after a manual power cycle, starting with an Event 41 to indicate improper shutdown, with no further info.
- Crash dump is on, but there is no MEMORY.DMP file at all.
- sfc /scannow
- I monitor system temps, CPU and GPU are in the mid 40s during general use

I've read through [Event ID 41](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028504/windows-kernel-event-id-41-error-the-system-has-rebooted-without-clean) and this sounds like a hard hang. However, this is all new hardware and a beefy PSU with no overclocking. Cooling is fine and system doesn't even have to be under load.

I'm at a real loss for how to get any visibility in to the problem, much less what to fix.

Comment: Have you searched for your issue with your motherboard model? Are you sure nothing is shorted, no even slightly bent pins, all mobo standoffs are correctly installed? Could you try lowering RAM frequency? Overvolt everything. Also try another OS (e.g. Ubuntu) run it for a while and check. If you aren't familiar with it, you don't even have to install it on your computer, you can just create a live USB. Additionally, have you tried rebuilding? I can really sympathize with this sort of issue, as I am still experiencing something of that sort on my Asus MOBO, GTX 1080, Skylake system.